# Testing an expected order of an array in RSpec / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In a RSpec spec file I have the following test

```
it 'should return 5 players with ratings closest to the current_users rating' do
  matched_players = User.find(:all, 
                              :select => ["*,(abs(rating - current_user.rating)) as player_rating"], 
                              :order => "player_rating", 
                              :limit => 5)

  # test that matched_players array returns what it is suppose to 
end
```

How would I complete this to test that matched_players is returning the correct users.

Comment: How do you determine "the correct users"?  Determine the array you want to have matched and test that it does.

Comment: The title of this question could probably be improved because it looks like a pure Ruby question when in reality this is a test question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your model shouldn't know about your current user (the controllers know about this concept)
- You need to extract this as a method on the User class otherwise there's no point in testing it, i.e. why test logic that isn't even in your app code?
- The function that gets the matched players doesn't need to know about the current user, or any user for that matter, just the rating.
- To test it, create a bunch of User instances, call the method, and see that the result is a list of the correct user instances you expect.

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.matched_players(current_user_rating)
    find(:all,
         select: ["*,(abs(rating - #{current_user_rating)) as match_strength"], 
         order: "match_strength", 
         limit: 5)
  end
  ...
end
```

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
describe User do
  ...
  describe "::matched_players" do
    context "when there are at least 5 users" do
      before do
        10.times.each do |n|
          instance_variable_set "@user#{n}", User.create(rating: n)
        end
      end

      it "returns 5 users whose ratings are closest to the given rating, ordered by closeness" do
        matched_players = described_class.matched_players(4.2)

        matched_players.should == [@user4, @user5, @user3, @user6, @user2]
      end

      context "when multiple players have ratings close to the given rating and are equidistant" do
        # we don't care how 'ties' are broken
        it "returns 5 users whose ratings are closest to the given rating, ordered by closeness" do
          matched_players = described_class.matched_players(4)

          matched_players[0].should == @user4
          matched_players[1,2].should =~ [@user5, @user3]
          matched_players[3,4].should =~ [@user6, @user2]
        end
      end
    end

    context "when there are fewer than 5 players in total" do
      ...
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should first introduce some test users to the test DB (using for example a Factory) and afterwards see that the test is returning the correct ones.

Also it would make more sense to have a method in your model that would return the matched users.

For example:

```
describe "Player matching" do
  before(:each) do
    @user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :rating => 5)
    ...
    @user7 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :rating => 3)
  end

  it 'should return 5 players with ratings closest to the current_users rating' do
    matched_players = User.matched_players
    matched_players.should eql [@user1,@user3,@user4,@user5,@user6]
  end
end
```